# Android Package: extra-android-support One or more required packages are missing. Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, ionic-framework, taco

I'm having trouble putting all my Android dependencies working with Visual Studio when using the TACO tools. 
The message that I get is that the extra-android-support package is missing, but I've already checked the Android Support Repository and the Google Repository on the Android SDK Manager. 
I only have one Android SDK installed, so I'm sure that I have the correct directory selected.
My SDK Manager looks like this:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY7DN.jpg)

I've already searched on the internet what could be generating this problem but I can't find a solution that works for me.

I've also tried building the solution with android studio but the app crashed when accessing some functionalities that require the missing package.

What I get is this:

```html
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener()...
```

Does anyone have a clue what this might be? I'd appreciate if anyone could help me.